# wget :: rename downloaded files and only download if newer

Tags: wget

I am trying to use `wget` to download a file under a different local name *and* only download if the file on the server is newer.

What I thought I could do was use the `-O` option of `wget` so as to be able to choose the name of the downloaded file, as in:

```
wget http://example.com/weird-name -O local-name
```

**and** combine that with the `-N` option that doesn't download anything except if the timestamp is newer on the server. For reasons explained in the comments below, `wget` refuses to combine both flags:

```
WARNING: timestamping does nothing in combination with -O. See the manual
for details.
```

Any ideas on succinct work-arounds ?

Comment: What is your goal? man wget explains why is pointless to mix -N with -O, since: -O is not intended to mean simply "use the name file instead of the one in the URL;" rather, it is analogous to shell redirection. In short your output file will always be newer than in server and nothing will be ever downloaded.

Comment: I suppose the actual question is "what's the idiomatic way in wget/bash to rename downloaded files **and** only download them if they are newer on the server" - I've rephrased the question to make that clear.

Comment: @ecelis if I get you and what `man wget` says right, that means that the `-O` file is always re-written / truncated the moment you run `wget` and so its timestamp is always NOW, in which case download is never triggered. Right?

Comment: Thats right. I was thinking, maybe something like wget -c -N URL:// could work for you. Of course you won't be able to define the output file name.

Answer (score 2):

Download it, then create a link

```
wget -N example.com/weird-name
ln weird-name local-name
```

After that you can run `wget -N` and it will work as expected:

- Only download if newer
- If a new file is downloaded it will be accessible from either name, without
  costing you extra drive space

Comment: This could work unless the reason you were using `-O` is because you were downloading a file of the same from several sources into the same directory. For example, if you were downloading several robots.txt files.

Answer (score 2):

If using other tool is possible in your case, I recommend the free, open source `lwp-mirror`:

```
lwp-mirror [-options] <url> <file>
```

It works just as you wish, with no workarounds.

This command is provided by the `libwww-perl` package on Ubuntu and Debian among other places.

Note that `lwp-mirror` doesn't support all of `wget`'s other features. For example, it doesn't allow you to set a User Agent for the request like `wget` does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` as an alternative:

```bash
curl example.com/weird-name -o local-name -z local-name
```

Related: https://superuser.com/a/908523